# On the lack of examples showing the importance of Morita equivalent rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory

We say two rings $R$ and $S$ are **Morita equivalent**, denoted $R \approx S$, if the categories of modules $Mod(R)$ are $Mod(S)$ are equivalent. For the neophyte in the topic like me, its not difficult to find information about  plenty examples of rings that are Morita equivalent, there are also a lot examples of properties preserved under Morita equivalence. Just take a glance to the Morita equivalences, Wikipedia article and its references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence

But so far, I have realized there are not  examples showing the importance of the Morita equivaleces in a handy situation, or in the proof of some important result. It springs to my mind using Morita equivalences theory to proof the  ring of squared matrix $M_{n}(K)$ over a field $K$ and size $n \times n$ is simple. That is proving the ring $M_{n}(K)$ doesn't have bilateral ideals. As it is well know that the rings $M_{n}(K)$ and $K$ are Morita equivalent, $M_{n}(K) \approx K$. On the other hand, by the fact that $K$ is a simple ring and being a simple ring is a property preserved under Morita equivalences, it yields that $M_{n}(K)$ is a simple ring.

Besides this simple example, Im run out of examples showing the importance of Morita equivalences theory. I would appreciate any other practical examples, or some more historical examples when Morita equivalences were helpful. Thanks